# Html : Text width is different than summation of its character's width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to calculate the text width without appending it to DOM.For this,i calculate and save each character's width i.e from (A-Z & a-z and other necessary characters).

Code :

```
function calculateCharactersWidth(){
    for(var i=65;i<123;i++){
        var x = $('<div style="float:left">').text(String.fromCharCode(i)).appendTo('#hiddenView');
        charactersWidth[i] = x.width();
        remHeight = x.height();
    }
    var x = $('<div style="float:left">').text(String.fromCharCode(45)).appendTo('#hiddenView');
    charactersWidth[45] = x.width();
    $('#hiddenView').empty();
}
```

and get each word's width like this

```
function getStringWidth(word){
    var width=0;
    for(var i=0;i<word.length;i++){
        width=width+charactersWidth[word.charAt(i).charCodeAt(0)];
    }
    return width;
}
```

but when the word is appended to DOM. Its width differs from the calculated width.In some cases it differs by 3-4 px.

Even if we calculate it like this

```
// css font-weight:bold and font-size:14px
<div>Absin</div>   width = 35.031

<div>A</div>      width = 10.125
<div>b</div>      width = 7.797
<div>s</div>      width = 6.219
<div>i</div>      width = 7
<div>n</div>      width = 4.672

Added width = 35.831
```

This small difference creates a huge difference with array of words.So why is the difference and how can i make it work?

Comment: What about little space between two chars?

Comment: This _might_ work if you used a `monospace` type font-- otherwise, I think the [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) might be tripping you up...  You might be better served by just rendering the text to the screen but with a large negative left margin so it isn't visible-- feels hacky, but will provide you more meaningful results.

Comment: @AlexanderNied : yes it works with monospace font..but still wanted to make it work with other fonts as well

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that might be impossible given the nature of non-monospace fonts...  Hopefully someone else will come along and prove me wrong.

Comment: Instead of calculating per character, you could just keep a hidden element in the DOM, then set text and measure the whole thing when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The kerning of the font is definitely messing up your calculation.
I am not sure why you'd need to do this, but why don't you print out your text in a hidden element and take the width of that?

```
function getStringWidth(word){
  var x = $('<div style="float:left">').text(word).appendTo('#hiddenView');

  return x.clientWidth;
}
```

This way you can also change the style, the font type and size, etc.

Comment: Don't forget to clean up, otherwise you may end up with thousands of DOM nodes. I'd personally just create one and re-use it every time updating its contents.

Comment: I first tried this but it is really slow.Actually i have big array of words to  display on screen.So for each word it would do append and remove.This is want i want to avoid. I am calculating like that so i can use .html().